# XSL font-size calculation

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm new in xsl, and have a question about the calculation of font-size.

I always use a certain number in font-size like `font-size="16pt"`.

Is there any possibility that I can calculate the font-size?

I tried `font-size="100 div 5"` or using a parameter like `font-size="$fontsize"`
but neither works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried font-size="100 div 5" or using a parameter like font-size="$fontsize" but neither works fine.

Try:

```
font-size="{100 div 5}"
```

or:

```
font-size="{$fontsize}"
```

For explanation, see: [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)

---

Note that you can always use the more verbose method:

```
<xsl:attribute name="font">
    <xsl:value-of select="100 div 5"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: `font-size="{100 div 5}pt"` or, if `$fontsize` is just a number, `font-size="{$fontsize}pt"`.